# Clojure sending data with nested vector to function and use the items

Tags: clojure

First, I'm sorry if my question is something simple or not clear. I'm almost new to Clojure and I need help.

I want to create a function to generate some HTML link for a menu. This is what I have now and it works fin:

```
(defn test-function [title-id title-name]
    [:span {:onclick #(.scrollIntoView (.getElementById js/document title-id))
            :style {:color :red} title-name])


[:li (test-function "title-1-id" "title-1-name")]
[:li (test-function "title-2-id" "title-2-name")]
```

But as I have many **li** tags, I want to have something like this to send to the function, and the function can generate the links for me, exactly like what the current code do for me. But I didn't find how to do that yet, and have no idea if I should use vector or something else.

```
[["title-1-id" "title-1-name"] ["title-2-id" "title-2-name"]]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this could be just `(mapv (fn [[id name]] [:li (test-function id name)]) [["title-1-id" "title-1-name"] ["title-2-id" "title-2-name"]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`for`](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/for), then [destructure](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) each element into `id` and `name` (I just renamed `name` to `li-name` to avoid shadowing function [`name`](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/name)) and wrap whole `for` in `[:ul ... ]`:

```
[:ul
             (for [[li-id li-name] [["id1" "Scroll to red"] ["id2" "Scroll to pink"]]]
                  [:li {:style {:cursor :pointer
                                :color :red}
                        :on-click #(.scrollIntoView (.getElementById js/document li-id))}
                   li-name])]

[:div
             [:div [:img#id1 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "red"}}]]
             [:div [:img#id2 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "pink"}}]]
             [:div [:img#id3 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "yellow"}}]]]
```

Note that you even don't need Javascript to scroll to target element- `[:a ... ]` can point to the object on the same page:

```
[:ul
             (for [[li-id li-name] [["id1" "Scroll to red"] ["id2" "Scroll to pink"]]]
                  [:a {:href  (str "#" li-id)
                       :style {:color           :red
                               :cursor          :pointer
                               :text-decoration :none}}
                   [:li li-name]])]
            [:div
             [:div [:img#id1 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "red"}}]]
             [:div [:img#id2 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "pink"}}]]
             [:div [:img#id3 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "yellow"}}]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin. It works fine :) About the a tag, I want to have the behavior smooth for scrolling, that's on of the reasons I'm using Javascript.